# How do I find the Thevenin voltage and resistance equations of this circuit?

Tags: voltage, resistance, thevenin, circuits

How do I find the Thevenin voltage and resistance equations of this circuit, with respect to the terminals U and G when Rc, Vc, Rt, and Rtrans are given?

[image: Picture of circuit]

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! Is this homework?

Comment: Thank you, It's an example question to practise with.

Comment: Please flag your question with the homework tag, take the Tour at https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tour and be adviced that we do offer homework help here _if_ you manage to show where you got stuck.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! This appears to be a homework question. As such, you need to show us your work so far, and explain which part of the question you're having trouble with. For future reference: Homework questions on EE.SE enjoy/suffer a special treatment. We don't provide complete answers, we only provide hints or Socratic questions, and only when you have demonstrated sufficient effort of your own. Otherwise, we would be doing you a disservice, and getting swamped by homework questions at the same time. See also [here](http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/a/5120/7036).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **KVL** in the center of the diagram should be a huge clue.

The Thévenin voltage is the open-circuit voltage. This is a moderately complex equation, but there's only one unknown: I<sub>R</sub>

You can easily get the short-circuit current by adding up the contributions of the two branches. Again, I<sub>R</sub> is the only unknown.

The Thévenin resistance is the ratio of those two results, by Ohm's Law.

Comment: Thank you for the response, what does the KVL in that direction reference? Is it referencing the direction of current within the circuit?

Comment: KVL = "[Kirchhoff's Voltage Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws)" -- specifically, the sum of the voltages around any closed loop is zero.